# Is there any theorem related to this statement that $ac= qn +1$ is true for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is a problem taken from chapter $1$ of Dummit and Foote book

Show that  if $n$  is not prime  then $ \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ is not a field

My attempt : I got this answer from solution manual of Dummit and Foote  written by James Ha

Consider  the set $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n$ is not prime then there exist  positive integer  $a, b$ such that $ n= ab$ and $ a, b >1$ . Suppose there exist a multiplicative inverse $\bar c$  of $\bar a $.Then it must  be true  that $ac= qn +1$  for some  $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ .However  ,$n=ab $ so $ac= qn +1 = q ab +1$ from which it follow that  $a(c-qb)=1$ .This is impossible  because  $a> 1!$

So $\bar a$ has no inverse  in $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} /n\mathbb{Z} - \{0\} , .)$ is not a group. we  must conclude that  $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$  is not field  for $n$  not prime

**My Doubt**: I'm not getting this line  then it must  be true  that $ac= qn +1$  for some  $q \in \mathbb{Z}$

My confusion is that why  it is written that $ac= qn +1$  is true for some  $q \in \mathbb{Z}?  $

Is there any theorem related to this statement? I was searching this related statement in Dummit  Foote book  but didn't found its

Comment: $\bar a\bar c=1$ means $ac-1\in n\Bbb Z$. So $ac-1=qn$ for some $q\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it more easily. If $n=ab$, with $1 < a,b < n$, then you have in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
$$\overline{a} \neq 0, \quad \overline{b} \neq 0, \quad \text{ but} \quad\overline{a}. \overline{b} = 0$$

So $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain, so it is not a field.